# Download de arquivo txt com ASP.NET Web Forms incluindo HTML da página no arquivo

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou fazendo download de arquivos com ASP.NET Web Forms no evento do clique de um LinkButton da seguinte forma:

```
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.Name));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
```

O código funciona, porém quando o arquivo é um `.txt` o mesmo, além de seu conteúdo original, vem com todo o HTML da página atual. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Isso é ASP.NET MVC, WebForms, WebAPI... poderia postar mais detalhes do contexto em que está executando o código que indicou?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo editei a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você está executando algum código ainda após escrever o arquivo na saída.

Use o método `Response.Flush` para garantir a escrita do arquivo na `Stream` de resposta, e logo depois chame `Response.End` para terminar de vez com qualquer código subsequente.

```
var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                                          + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.Name));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Utilizei apenas o método Response.End e funcionou, como você disse, algo provavelmente está sendo executado após a chamada do método, vou ver se descubro o que é...

Comment: Como o método é executado no servidor por meio de post, poderia estar adicionando o conteúdo do arquivo no content da response e por ser text, estar incluindo o html, já que a pagina é renderizada novamente? Faz sentido?

Comment: Total sentido. O WebForms tem um [ciclo-de-vida](http://eysermans.com/images/articles/show-load-time-of-a-page-with-asp-net/03-aspnet-page-control-life-cycle.jpg) muito complexo, então dependendo de onde exatamente está o código acima, dentro deste ciclo, os passos seguintes do ciclo seriam executados.